# How do I download ReactOS Kernel source?

Tags: react-os

I would like to download the ReactOS Kernel Source Code for a project (because Windows_NT is closed source). I just want the kernel source, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReactOS kernel is named ntoskrnl. You can check it out (using SVN) on https://svn.reactos.org/reactos/trunk/reactos/ntoskrnl/
Note that the kernel is strictly tied to the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) which you might need as well: https://svn.reactos.org/reactos/trunk/reactos/hal/

This will allow you to download ReactOS and explore offline its source code. However, you won't be able to build it: you will lack dependencies, tools required for compilation, and various configuration files. The proper way to build ReactOS is described here: https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Building_ReactOS. You need a full source checkout to be able to proceed, along with the official ReactOS Build Environment (RosBE).

If you just want to browse it (no build), then I'd recommend you do it online, either by using: http://code.reactos.org/, https://git.reactos.org/?p=reactos.git;a=summary, https://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/ or http://doxygen.reactos.org/. So that you're sure to always look at the latest version of the code available.

Comment: Is is possible to build just the kernel, and then make the rest of the os? I am just need the kernel for this project, I will make everything else. Also, is it possible to use grub as the kernel bootloader?

Comment: What are the dependencies that it is missing and where are they located?

Comment: It is possible to make a new OS on top of the kernel. GRUB is not able to load any NT-compatible OS: it just chainloads to Ntldr/Winldr/FreeLdr (this is ReactOS bootloader) to do so. As for the dependencies, I recommend you have a look at the ntoskrnl CMakeLists.txt file. You'll find them in target_link_libraries, add_importlibs, add_dependencies definitions.

Comment: **Thank you!** I am going to ask any more questions in the comments of this if I need any more help.

Comment: StackOverflow recommends from not abusing comments. If you have any further questions, I'd recommend you open a topic on [ReactOS boards](https://www.reactos.org/forum) to ask about how to properly handle the source code.
Don't forget to accept the answer ;-)